# Should StartsWith only be used for ordering?

Tags: c#, string

I was reading Microsoft's [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx).

It gives the following example as an introduction to `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
public static bool IsFileURI(string path) 
{
    return path.StartsWith("FILE:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

So far, so good. But it then goes on to say this:

> However, the preceding example uses the `String.StartsWith(String, StringComparison)` method to test for equality. **Because the purpose of the comparison is to test for equality instead of ordering the strings, a better alternative is to call the `Equals` method, as shown in the following example.**

```
public static bool IsFileURI(string path)
{
    if (path.Length < 5) return false;

    return String.Equals(path.Substring(0, 5), "FILE:", 
                         StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

I'm struggling to see why the second version is better. I could understand switching from `CompareTo` (comparison) to `Equals` (equality), but isn't `StartsWith` also an equality test? Am I missing something or is this a documentation bug?

Comment: Despite what documentation may say, I'd prefer the first version in almost every situation. It's much clearer and I can't think of a case in which the outputs could possibly differ.

Comment: With StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, both StartsWith and Equals call TextInfo.InternalCompareStringOrdinalIgnoreCase, so they end up the same under the hood. I wouldn't call it a documentation 'bug', but it's definitely an example that could use improving.

Comment: As a note, `String.StartsWith` throws an exception if the string to compare with is `null`, while `String.Equals` does not through if any of the two compared strings are `null`. However, this has nothing t do probably with that recommendation.

Comment: `"fıle:///C:/".StartsWith("FILE:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` returns false, as does `FİLE`, so I think your comparison is safe on internationalization issues. (That's Turkish 'lower dotless i' and 'captial dotted I'.)

Comment: The substring advice in that document is just garbage. Don't take the docs too literally.

Comment: how is it better : performance ? error handling ? code quality ? as often, it depends on your use case...

Comment: They both use an ordering comparison function under the hood.  Maybe this was true back in .NET 1.x, it isn't today.

Comment: @HansPassant This documentation is disponible only for.Net 4.0, 4.5 and Silverlight.

Comment: Another difference - if the path variable is less than 5 characters somehow, the second will produce an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` whereas the first would not.

Comment: The documentation does seem a little strange. Say I have the string `München` and want to check if it start with `Mü`. Using `SubString` with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` would return `false` but `StartWidth` `true`.

Comment: @Magnus both will return `true` if you pass **3** to `String.SubString` (the diaeresis is an additional Unicode character). I still think you're right though, one shouldn't think about these things and just use `String.StartsWith`...

Answer (score 3):

Not a real answer, but `StartsWith()` is an equality test and I think it's a **documentation bug**, but I was curious to know the performances, so I did a banchmark using the following code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew( );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ) //1 billion times
            IsFileURI1( "File:\\ThisIsATest" );
        sw.Stop( );
        Console.WriteLine( "String.StartsWith(): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString( ) );

        sw.Restart( );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ) //1 billion times
            IsFileURI2( "File:\\ThisIsATest" );
        sw.Stop( );
        Console.WriteLine( "String.Equals(): " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString( ) );
    }

    public static bool IsFileURI1( string path ) {
        return path.StartsWith( "FILE:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
    }

    public static bool IsFileURI2( string path ) {
        if ( path.Length < 5 ) return false;

        return String.Equals( path.Substring( 0, 5 ), "FILE:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
    }   
}
```

The results are (*milliseconds*):

```
String.StartsWith(): 90102 
String.Equals(): 73113
```

So in terms of performance the second solution is better and is about the **20% faster**.

Comment: This is completely unexpected, since the `Substring()` call creates a whole new string object as overhead. In any case, unless you're doing this with millions of strings, I'd go with the more readable version over the slightly faster one.

Comment: When I run the code specified i get `StartsWith` 1536 and `Equals` 8846.